# Cant install repforge on Centos 5

Tags: centos, rpm

```
rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Retrieving http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
error: skipping http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
```

or

```
pm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Retrieving http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
error: skipping http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had a problem downloading the file. FWIW I was just able to download the file without a problem. It's most likely a transient but you could always try downloading direct from a [mirror](http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/dag/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm), of which there are [many](http://mirror-status.repoforge.org/).